# Praat Integration in Python 2/3

Tags: python, machine-learning, integration, audio-analysis, praat

I've been working on Praat for some audio analysis stuff. However, I found some libraries that use Praat in Python and would like to do the same.

This site offers a lot of features that can be extracted when praat is used. I have followed he instructions for "integrating" it in python. http://homepage.univie.ac.at/christian.herbst//python/index.html
However, I couldn't get it to work. It returns the error:\
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I also found another library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-praat-scripts. This also returns the error (when I run the code below): OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

```
from praatinterface import PraatLoader
pl = PraatLoader(praatpath ='/Users/user/Downloads/praat6015_mac64.dmg')
text = pl.run_script('formants.praat', 'sample.wav', 5, 5500)
formants = pl.read_praat_out(text)
```

It would be great if someone can help me integrate praat to python properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*[Disclaimer: I am the author of the mentioned Parselmouth library]*

If you do not mind trying yet another library, [Parselmouth](https://github.com/YannickJadoul/Parselmouth) integrates Praat into Python without the need for an external Praat binary:

```
import parselmouth
resulting_objects = parselmouth.praat.run_file('formants.praat', 'sample.wav', 5, 5500)
```

The `resulting_objects` variable will contain a list of the Praat objects that are selected, so if you make sure to select the `Formant` object, that will be returned. Alternatively, if you want to capture the output window, run

```
import parselmouth
output_string = parselmouth.praat.run_file('formants.praat', 'sample.wav', 5, 5500, capture_output=True)
```

Yet another alternative is to call the analysis from Python itself, and do something like this:

```
import parselmouth
sound = parselmouth.Sound("sample.wav")
formant = sound.to_formant_burg(max_number_of_formants=5, maximum_formant=5500)
formant.get_value_at_time(3, 0.5) # For the value of formant 3 at 0.5 seconds
```

Comment: Hello Yannick, i use this : `objects = parselmouth.praat.run_file('crosscorelate.praat', wav_filename1, wav_filename2, capture_output=True)` but i get the error `parselmouth.PraatError: Found 2 arguments but expected more. Script not completed.` even though it's working with the binary executable : `Praat.exe crosscorelate.praat one.wav two/wav` what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Hello Narthe. It's hard to see from this one line (without the script). The error comes from somewhere inside Praat, but the error might be in my code linking Python to Praat. I'd be very happy to look into this and solve it, though!
Could you somehow get me some more information or the script? If easier, you could open an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/YannickJadoul/Parselmouth/issues), or talk further on Gitter (https://gitter.im/PraatParselmouth/Lobby)

Comment: @Narthe I think I understand the problem. Parselmouth checks the amount of parameters to your script, while Praat does not and leave them undefined or empty if you do not give enough parameters. The solution is to either pass the extra parameters needed to the Praat script (see the 'form' construct in the script), or to remove unnecessary parameters from the 'form' in the script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yannick ! It was really dumb of me, i didn't check the praat script and it has 2 additionnal parameters with a default value, so that's why it was working with the executable.

Comment: @Narthe Good to hear it works! :-) It's not really you, though: Praat will not check the number of arguments from the command line, and as far as I tested, it will also not insert the default parameters. (If you're using the same `'crosscorelate.praat'` that I found online, the two last parameters are not used, and that's why their `undefined` value does not cause any trouble.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used any of your tools, but it seems the problem might be with your `praatpath` variable. In the pages you link to, they are supposed to point to the Praat binary, whereas in your example you have them pointing to the Praat archive with the 64-bit Mac release.

You'll have to install Praat first. The instructions are pretty standard, but quoting from the Praat website:

> After downloading, your web browser might open the `.dmg` file directly; you will then see the program `Praat` or `Praat.app`. If your browser did not open the `.dmg` file, then you should double-click the `.dmg` file in the Downloads window (or in the Downloads folder in your home directory); after double-clicking you may see the program `Praat` or `Praat.app` directly, or you may see a disk icon called `Praat6016`, which when you open it will show you the program `Praat` or `Praat.app`. To install Praat, just drag the program `Praat` or `Praat.app` to your *Applications* folder (or anywhere else).

Once that is done, the `praatpath` variable should point to this executable.

This applies to your second example, but I suspect that the problem might be similar for the first (ie. it doesn't know where Praat is, because it is either not installed or not in `PATH`).

Comment: I've installed praat but the praatath command still returns the same error.

Comment: The `praatpath` _command_? You mean the option on your script? What path did you set it to?

Comment: i set it to the praat directory or where the praat program is located

Comment: It should point to the Praat binary, not its directory. See if that works.

Comment: how do you locate the praat binary?

Comment: The binary is the executable. When you run Praat, you need to execute that file. So, if you say "the praat program is located" in, say `/home/user/bin`, and that's the directory, then the path to the executable would be something like `/home/user/bin/praat`.